# Gettextbounds in android

Tags: android

We used to find the rectangle which fits the given text, for example if give "TESTING" in gettextbounds api it will give a rectangle that fits the given string "TESTING", but could any plz clarify on which basis the rectangle length is calculated, whether the font size will be considered if so is it possible for me to check like this ?

1) Way i tried
        CharSequence text = getText();
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, text.length(), mTextX, mTextY, getPaint());

```
    Paint pt = new Paint ( );
    pt.setTextSize(10);

    TextPaint tp = getPaint();
    String string = "haa";
    Rect currentBounds = new Rect ( );
    //this.setTextSize(/* TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX */ 10, /* fontPixelSize*Home.fltFontRatio */ 32);

    tp.getTextBounds((String) text, 0, text.length(), currentBounds );

    Log.e ( " ", "Desired Text " +text);
    Log.e ( " ", "first Ondraw Left " +currentBounds.left);
    Log.e ( " ", "Ondraw Top" +currentBounds.top);
    Log.e ( " ", "Ondraw right " +currentBounds.right);
    Log.e ( " ", "Ondraw bottom " +currentBounds.bottom);

    pt.setTextSize(20);


    tp.getTextBounds((String) text, 0, text.length(), currentBounds );

    Log.e ( "", "Desired Text " +text);
    Log.e ( " ", "Second Ondraw Left " +currentBounds.left);
    Log.e ( " ", "Ondraw Top" +currentBounds.top);
    Log.e ( " ", "Ondraw right " +currentBounds.right);
    Log.e ( "Nrace ", "Ondraw bottom " +currentBounds.bottom);
```

### 2)  Second way i tried

```
    TextPaint tp = getPaint();
    String string = "haa";
    Rect currentBounds = new Rect ( );
    this.setTextSize(/* TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX */ 10, /* fontPixelSize*Home.fltFontRatio */ 32);               

    tp.getTextBounds(string, 0, string.length(), currentBounds );

    Log.e ( " ", "first Left " +currentBounds.left);
    Log.e ( " ", "Top" +currentBounds.top);
    Log.e ( " ", "right " +currentBounds.right);
    Log.e ( " ", "bottom " +currentBounds.bottom);

    this.setTextSize(/* TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX */ 10, /* fontPixelSize*Home.fltFontRatio */ 10);

    tp.getTextBounds(string, 0, string.length(), currentBounds );

    Log.e ( " ", "Sefond Left " +currentBounds.left);
    Log.e ( " ", "Top" +currentBounds.top);
    Log.e ( " ", "right " +currentBounds.right);
    Log.e ( "", "bottom " +currentBounds.bottom);
```

In the above two methods am trying to find out the various rectangle size for the given text size. if this is not a good way plz advise me by posting some sample codes. Simply to say i have to find the various rectangle which fits the text "TESTING" for various font size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 53):

I find this part of the API quite confusing, however I think I almost understood how it works. A call to getTextBounds() returns the smallest rectangle that would enclose all the characters drawn by a subsequent call to drawText() with x=0 and y=0. This is stated in slightly different words on the [API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29). Everything that is in Paint and could affect the appearance of the text is taken into account. Here's an example:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
paint.setTypeface(typeface);
paint.setTextSize(textSize);
paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
```

The reason why the rectangle has such *exotic* coordinates is because when you draw text with drawText(), the origin to which x and y are relative depends on the typographical properties of the Paint that you selected. For instance y is relative to the baseline, which is neither above nor below the font, but usually strikes it somewhere across the middle. For this reason the bounds rectangle will have (usually) a negative top and a positive bottom. The negative top means that the top of the text is *above* the baseline (y decreases going up), while the positive bottom means that the bottom of the text is *below* the baseline (y increases going down). It is interesting to note that when you measure a string such as "Hi" the bottom is likely to be 0, because those characters do not have a *below the baseline* part. On the contrary, when you measure a string like "Hg" you are likely to get a positive bottom, because the *story* of the g is below the baseline. I'm not sure how the horizontal position is estimated, though.

With this said, to draw the text of which you have computed the bounds you can do:

```
canvas.drawText(text, -bounds.left, -bounds.top, paint);
```

This will draw the text near to the upper left corner of the canvas. The coordinates of the upper left corner are (0, 0) so to move the text around you only have to add your desired amount of displacement:

```
canvas.drawText(text, -bounds.left + yourX, -bounds.top + yourY, paint);
```

Another example: if you want to create a bitmap that contains text, and you want to fit exactly the available space, you can do:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bounds.width(), bounds.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawText(text, -bounds.left, -bounds.top, paint);
```

If you want to leave a few pixels to the left, right, top and bottom, let's say 2, you can do:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bounds.width() + 4, bounds.height() + 4, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawText(text, -bounds.left + 2, -bounds.top + 2, paint);
```

Comment: I've been experimenting with this a few other times, and I'm pretty sure that the answer is correct. Did it work for you? If that's the case maybe you could accept the answer, it may help other people in the same situation.

Comment: Doing exactly as stated in this answer doesn't work for me, it's still a few pixels out sometimes. However, using `Paint.measureText()` always works.

Comment: That is probably the problem mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549182/android-paint-measuretext-vs-gettextbounds?lq=1 however the question asked about  **getTextBounds** and in particular to *clarify on which basis the rectangle length is calculated, whether the font size will be considered if so is it possible for me to check like this*.

Comment: Informative info about getTextBounds, thanks. Though for anyone who comes here, Alex Chi's looks like a more reliable solution, since it uses measureText to get the width. (and as OP said "if this is not a good way plz advise me")

Comment: Ah, Prizoff explains http://stackoverflow.com/a/15398496/199364 what is not made clear in this answer. To correctly measure needed width using bounds, must do `bounds.left + bounds.width()`. Perhaps `left` is slight empty space before first visible pixel, and `width` is the width of the actually drawn pixels.

Comment: you define well, there is a shortcut for this  try setting paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT); and we are good to go.

Answer (score 4):

There are some nuances, so it is better once to see...
Red rectangle shows text bounds, x,y - any coordinates (of left lower point of the text bounds)

```
Rect textBounds = new Rect();
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
Paint rectPaint = new Paint();
String text = "java m";

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    textPaint.setTextSize(100);
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);

    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, textPaint);

    rectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    rectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    canvas.drawRect(
            x,                       // left
            y - textBounds.height(), // top
            x + textBounds.width(),  // right
            y,                       // bottom
            rectPaint);
}
```

text = "Hello Worlds"

[image]

text = "java m"

[image]

Comment: Paint.Align textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT; should be this in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that works for me: use `Paint.measureText(text)` to get `text`'s width and `Paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds)` to get `text`'s height (`height = bounds.height()`)

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
class Pos {
  public int X;
  public int Y;
}
public static void getTextPositionAndRealBound(Paint paint, String text, int x, int y, Pos pos, Rect bound) {
  paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bound);
  // in X
  bound.left = x;
  bound.right = (int)(paint.measureText(text) + 0.5); // .5f to 1

  // in Y
  y = y - bound.top;
  bound.top = y;
  bound.bottom = bound.height();

  // reset the position
  pos.X = x;
  pos.Y = y;
}
```

You know that the X is right and the Y is down in the coord of the bound by getTextBounds.

The solution can get the position and real bound of text. You can move the text to any position, just edit the var - pos and use it when call Canvas.drawText like this:

```
Pos pos;
Rect bound;
getTextPositionAndRealBound(paint, text, x, y, pos, bound);
canvas.drawText(text, pos.X, pos.Y, paint);
```

Note: thanks for @ToolmakerSteve advice

Comment: If calling repeatedly for different texts, is important to initialize pos.Y before each call, since this method alters it. Such is the danger of modifying input parameters. IMHO less risky is `(Paint paint, String text, int x, int y, Pos outPos, Rect bound)` where `x` and `y` are desired location. Then `..getTextBounds(..);  outPos.x = x; bound.left = x; bound.right = ..; outPos.Y = y - bound.top; bound.top = y; ..`  Note that there is no longer a local declaration `int y`, because we pass `y` in directly.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Right, I believe you are professional in Java. I will modify it. Many thanks.