# How Canvas.drawText() really draws the text?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

In this method documentation it's written that:

```
x   The x-coordinate of origin for where to draw the text
y   The y-coordinate of origin for where to draw the text
```

But it doesn't say anything about the direction this text is drawn. I know that the text is drawn from the origin up, but when I give the following arguments, my text gets cut:

```
canvas.drawText(displayText, 0, canvas.getHeight(), textPaint);
```

in addition, assume I'm using Align.LEFT (meaning that the text is drawn to the right of the x,y origin)

So what are the correct arguments should be (assuming I don't want to use fixed numbers)?

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for (check the comment on the answer). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606410/android-canvas-drawtext-y-position-of-text

Comment: how does the text get cut? Is any text even showing?

Comment: If you trying setting the y value to canvas.getHeight() / 2, does it correctly show the text appearing in the middle? Also, you should say what you want to accomplish more concretely.

Comment: getHeight/2 results in the text being cut as well, this time the upper part of the text is cut and not the bottom part of it as in the original situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I eventually used:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (textAlignment == Align.CENTER) {
        canvas.drawText(displayText, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()-TEXT_PADDING, textPaint);  
    }
    else if (textAlignment == Align.RIGHT) {
        canvas.drawText(displayText, canvas.getWidth()-TEXT_PADDING, canvas.getHeight()-TEXT_PADDING, textPaint);   
    }
    else if (textAlignment == Align.LEFT) {
        canvas.drawText(displayText, TEXT_PADDING, canvas.getHeight()-TEXT_PADDING, textPaint); 
    }   
    //canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), p);
}
```

Two comments:

1. TEXT_PADDING is a dp dimension I convert to pixels at runtime (in my case 3dp).
2. You can un-comment the the last line to draw the rect around your canvas for debug.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the following snippet to see if its working or not :

```
int width = this.getMeasuredWidth()/2;
int height = this.getMeasuredHeight()/2;
textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
canvas.drawText(displayText, width, height, textPaint);
```

The width and height are just calculated arbitrarily in my case.